# animationstart only triggers sometimes?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Hey guys following jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/Lvq6ee8d/12/

If this is being played in Safari, it works sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't. You can check the console to see the "hallo" being put out. In Chrome however, it's never being triggered.

So two questions:

Why is this working sometimes in Safari, and never in chrome and secondly:

Is there a working solution to this?

Html:

```
<img src="3ds_preset_gearshape.png" class="gwd-img-r1sa gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation" data-gwd-style="" data-gwd-override-style=""/>


<div id="play">
    click here to play
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-perspective: 1400px;
  -moz-perspective: 1400px;
  perspective: 1400px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.gwd-img-r1sa {
  position: absolute;
  width: 192px;
  height: 146px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  left: 312px;
  top: 604px;
  -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}

@-webkit-keyframes gwd-empty-animation {
  0% { opacity: 0.001; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes gwd-empty-animation {
  0% { opacity: 0.001; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes gwd-empty-animation {
  0% { opacity: 0.001; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation_gwd-keyframes {
  0% { left: 312px; top: 604px; -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; }
  30% { left: 595px; top: 350px; -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; }
  50% { left: 595px; top: 350px; -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.0510417556, 0.9986965201, 0, 0, -0.9986965201, 0.0510417556, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;}
  100% { left: 595px; top: 350px; -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.051, 0.9987, 0, 0, -0.9987, 0.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 312, 146, 0, 1); -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; }
}
@-moz-keyframes gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation_gwd-keyframes {
  0% { left: 312px; top: 604px; -moz-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; }
  30% { left: 595px; top: 350px; -moz-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; }
  50% { left: 595px; top: 350px; -moz-transform: matrix3d(0.0510417556, 0.9986965201, 0, 0, -0.9986965201, 0.0510417556, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; }
  100% { left: 595px; top: 350px; -moz-transform: matrix3d(0.051, 0.9987, 0, 0, -0.9987, 0.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 312, 146, 0, 1); -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; }
}
@keyframes gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation_gwd-keyframes {
  0% { left: 312px; top: 604px; transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); animation-timing-function: linear; }
  30% { left: 595px; top: 350px; transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); animation-timing-function: linear; }
  50% { left: 595px; top: 350px; transform: matrix3d(0.0510417556, 0.9986965201, 0, 0, -0.9986965201, 0.0510417556, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); animation-timing-function: linear; }
  100% { left: 595px; top: 350px; transform: matrix3d(0.051, 0.9987, 0, 0, -0.9987, 0.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 312, 146, 0, 1); animation-timing-function: linear; }
}
body .gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation {
  -webkit-animation: gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation_gwd-keyframes 3s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
  -moz-animation: gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation_gwd-keyframes 3s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
  animation: gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation_gwd-keyframes 3s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation").on('webkitAnimationStart oanimationstart msAnimationStart 
animationstart', function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".gwd-gen-hlergwdanimation").css({'-webkit-animation-play-state': 'paused','animation-play-state':'paused'})          
        },300);
    console.log('hallo');
    })
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: Because the animation, defined in CSS, should have already started before the JS has had a chance to run.

Comment: So how is it possible to wait for the js to be loaded, until the css code will been run? @JamesDonnelly is it really necessary to include the code when I use a jsfiddle?

Comment: @FrederikWitte yes it is. If JSFiddle goes down this question will be completely worthless as nobody will know what you're talking about.

Comment: True that, code added in question

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you are right, it works when you change onLoad to domReady in the jsfiddle. If you want, you can post an answer with a little explanation for people who might stumble over this, and I will pick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time the jQuery runs to attach the event, the CSS has already started the animation!

As a result, it can't fire the `animationstart` event because it's already done.

Try using `domReady` instead of `onLoad` (or - especially since you're using jQuery - just use `$(function() {...})` to wrap your code), as this will run much sooner and be able to attach the event before CSS animations start.